# Insert a few columns and rows from one dataframe into another dataframe with many more columns and rows

Tags: r, merge, subset

I have one very large dataframe (with more than 50 columns and many thousands of rows), a snippet of which is given in `df1`, and one very small dataframe with very few columns and rows, `df2`, which contains corrected data for `df1`:

Large:

```
df1 <- structure(list(File = c("F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01"), Line = c(991L, 992L, 993L, 950L, 951L, 952L, 953L), Speaker = c("ID01.B", 
NA, "ID01.A", "ID01.C", NA, "ID01.A", "ID01.B"), Sequ = c(30L, 
30L, 30L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), Q = c("q_pol", "q_pol", "q_pol", 
"q_pol", "q_pol", "q_pol", "q_pol"), N_ipu = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), Utterance = c("=do you guys need to go back to Ikea anytime soon¿ (.) I don't want=", 
"(0.038)", "=always=", "=so Monday?=", "(0.008)", "=hol[ler:::] if you want a ride", 
"[yeah]"), Timestamp = c("00:21:20.235 - 00:21:22.879", "00:21:22.879 - 00:21:22.917", 
"00:21:22.917 - 00:21:23.498", "00:20:31.650 - 00:20:32.222", 
"00:20:32.222 - 00:20:32.230", "00:20:32.230 - 00:20:34.527", 
"00:20:32.785 - 00:20:33.205"), Q_by = c("B", NA, NA, "C", NA, 
NA, NA), Answ_by = c("A", NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA), Aaoi = c("*B*B*B*", 
"*", "*", "*", "*", "*C*", "*"), Baoi = c("A*A", "A", "A", "*C", 
"C", "C*A", "C"), Caoi = c("A*B*B*", "*", "*A", "*", "*", "*A", 
"*"), Adur = c("732, 166, 884, 149, 451, 149, 113", "38", "581", 
"572", "8", "24, 102, 2171", "420"), Bdur = c("3, 321, 2320", 
"38", "581", "359, 213", "8", "1308, 571, 418", "420"), Cdur = c("400, 256, 244, 689, 728, 327", 
"38", "5, 576", "572", "8", "1428, 869", "420"), A_Area_av = c("601.4205,602.9385,608.225,611.9615,610.5655,606.266,613.946,604.808,606.0685,595.0545,588.8595,597.4305,590.1285,584.708,585.726,592.8125,586.041,587.092,585.0985,590.9365,588.0725,585.5485,579.7915,585.4685,580.6295,577.608,572.518,575.467,569.742,570.089,563.1095,559.8635,564.6895,563.046,562.6775,561.488,562.8215,567.387,562.438,559.921,571.306,564.5025,565.853,565.1765,541.471,558.825,598.7505,610.0795,593.092,599.506,591.9885,599.718,602.8275,608.196,603.5275,598.9005,607.75,612.698,609.5625,604.1775,601.688,609.648,615.5035,614.1635,615.255,626.5105,624.352,629.6365,628.1505,625.4695,635.789,635.255,651.533,652.318,654.3625,655.559,664.403,658.9375,660.656,659.857,662.136,675.203,674.083,687.4895,683.8915,685.74,698.915,702.4895,701.7415,697.51,703.551,708.525,703.544,706.546,702.0095,708.532,717.171,715.0815,712.4205,711.6725,722.6945,718.984,719.2275,725.508,732.165,723.4745,726.265,737.4115,730.967,728.307,733.776,720.9105,729.172,723.2725,738.4195,732.045,729.2465,735.0775,729.828,728.5605,727.8755,737.312,737.9625,738.217,731.503,736.6975,725.4055,737.313,731.536,725.0055,727.677,727.411,733.272,734.7145,734.8845,730.7515,741.0095,746.2205,743.1225,747.0055,735.6235,733.425,739.0075,739.7375,735.5125,737.8905,731.887,727.981,731.4055,727.752,719.715,713.2015,718.707,720.7465,713.2125,715.263,718.9595,717.134,716.4635,714.182", 
"714.182,702.4825,680.9495", "680.9495,694.641,697.939,692.9615,706.298,707.3705,716.398,723.045,720.074,727.4415,719.681,724.5255,727.8885,738.541,744.5745,747.894,765.7335,760.4365,757.6545,751.15,750.697,749.252,745.6615,736.7915,742.468,729.083,732.048,720.187,733.2215,712.975,731.7685,724.7865,725.428,734.7755,727.465,728.6105", 
"574.3445,577.8675,568.954,570.1815,568.3655,571.756,578.5075,570.2235,577.112,575.8575,580.1065,582.1745,576.067,582.5905,582.9315,581.9255,581.888,584.157,581.059,587.708,590.8625,592.9645,593.0105,591.879,597.643,594.915,601.693,601.9125,603.235,558.439,585.057,636.6355,688.616,726.5445,726.7685,732.7715", 
"732.7715", "732.7715,732.2835,742.525,732.129,736.7395,742.4785,741.538,741.134,740.0665,704.622,621.436,618.107,633.682,641.7885,633.3825,628.869,628.3315,624.074,619.971,621.133,614.118,608.018,602.63,598.8605,594.5405,589.108,591.7935,585.108,575.0235,582.0335,588.871,575.2915,587.99,581.7825,582.4725,576.851,585.7895,576.763,581.4595,585.989,581.46,587.1015,590.708,584.07,582.2705,589.4475,591.706,590.8365,592.9135,600.371,593.7015,601.208,594.07,605.5185,600.6945,609.5385,607.438,607.159,608.1535,608.954,601.5205,605.5925,607.205,603.8995,598.885,601.657,604.3665,608.3525,608.4205,610.66,604.0435,598.986,600.9705,596.2165,603.1145,598.789,594.9195,593.6315,593.909,595.245,591.667,593.7845,589.164,589.863,590.8055,596.932,593.0385,595.458,592.276,595.4075,598.09,600.6265,596.3265,594.757,594.7905,594.5465,588.441,591.6315,588.924,593.9225,585.254,591.2645,594.7905,591.9845,597.202,593.0845,596.483,592.9395,597.4135,591.844,592.969,589.7095,599.2825,595.434,593.1245,588.5705,597.613,592.668,591.312,594.684,590.88,598.1365,595.126,591.6835,598.502,603.444,601.417,608.247,602.8635,613.3065,604.812,610.6205,607.2485,612.363,604.8595,602.965,609.627,601.151,605.183", 
"581.7825,582.4725,576.851,585.7895,576.763,581.4595,585.989,581.46,587.1015,590.708,584.07,582.2705,589.4475,591.706,590.8365,592.9135,600.371,593.7015,601.208,594.07,605.5185,600.6945,609.5385,607.438,607.159,608.1535,608.954"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Small:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Utterance = c("=so Monday?=", "(0.008)", "=hol[ler:::] if you 
want a ride", "[yeah]"), Aaoi = c("B*C", "C", "C*B", "B"), Baoi = c("*C", "C", 
"C*A", "C"), Caoi = c("B", "B", "B*A", "B*"), Adur = c("463, 52, 57", 
"8", "91, 43, 2163", "420"), Bdur = c("356, 216", "8", "1256, 322, 719", 
"420"), Cdur = c("572", "8", "635, 410, 1252", "80, 340"), Sequ = c(28, 
28, 28, 28)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I need to do is **insert the corrected data in `df2` into `df1`**. The two dataframes share the columns in `df2`. The columns that contain identical values across `df1` and `df2` are `Utterance` and `Sequ`. The columns that contain the corrected data are: `Aaoi`, `Baoi`, `Caoi`, `Adur`, `Bdur`, and `Cdur`. How can I funnel these columns from `df2` into `df1` without inserting the changes one by one?

Comment: I would suggest a left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `tidyverse`. The idea of my solution is as follows:

- Binding the two dataframes, adding a new column `id` to distinguish the two dataframes.
- Then one groups by `Utterance` and `Sequ`, and, for the concerned columns, one takes the `last` value (using `mutate` and `across`).
- The referred `last` value contains the information of `df2`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(c(df2, id = 2)) %>% 
  group_by(Utterance, Sequ) %>% 
  mutate(across(c("Aaoi", "Baoi", "Caoi", "Adur", "Bdur", "Cdur"), last)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% filter(is.na(id)) %>% select(-id)

#> # A tibble: 7 × 17
#>   File   Line Speaker  Sequ Q     N_ipu Utterance  Timestamp Q_by  Answ_by Aaoi 
#>   <chr> <int> <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 F01     991 ID01.B     30 q_pol     1 =do you g… 00:21:20… B     A       *B*B…
#> 2 F01     992 <NA>       30 q_pol     0 (0.038)    00:21:22… <NA>  <NA>    *    
#> 3 F01     993 ID01.A     30 q_pol     1 =always=   00:21:22… <NA>  <NA>    *    
#> 4 F01     950 ID01.C     28 q_pol     1 =so Monda… 00:20:31… C     B       B*C  
#> 5 F01     951 <NA>       28 q_pol     0 (0.008)    00:20:32… <NA>  <NA>    C    
#> 6 F01     952 ID01.A     28 q_pol     1 =hol[ler:… 00:20:32… <NA>  <NA>    *C*  
#> 7 F01     953 ID01.B     28 q_pol     1 [yeah]     00:20:32… <NA>  <NA>    B    
#> # … with 6 more variables: Baoi <chr>, Caoi <chr>, Adur <chr>, Bdur <chr>,
#> #   Cdur <chr>, A_Area_av <chr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Respect for the complicated data you work with. Let me answer this with a somewhat simpler example. Consider these data frames `d1` and `d2`:

```
d1
#   id1 id2 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1   B   A  5  5  5  5  5
# 2   E   A  1  1  1  1  1
# 3   C   B  2  2  2  2  2
# 4   A   A  3  3  3  3  3
# 5   D   A  4  4  4  4  4

d2
#   id1 id2  X1  X2  X3  X4
# 2   E   A 200 300 400 100
# 1   B   A 300 400 100 200
# 3   C   B 100 200 300 400
```

You want to replace the data in `d1` with the data in `d2`, while identifying the correct rows.

To achieve this, you could first `match` the identifying columns of both data frames after you `paste`d them together, which will give you the row IDs of `d1` corresponding correctly to those of `d2`.

```
bys <- c('id1', 'id2')
(rows1 <- match(Reduce(paste, d2[bys]), Reduce(paste, d1[bys])))
# [1] 1 3 2
```

After that, just use the vector of the columns that are to be replaced to subset both data frames; `d1` you will also subset by the found row IDs in first step.

```
cols <- c('X1', 'X2', 'X3')
d1[rows1, cols] <- d2[, cols]
```

**Gives:**

```
d1
#   id1 id2  X1  X2  X3 X4 X5
# 1   A   B 200 300 100  4  4
# 2   E   B 400 200 300  1  1
# 3   D   B 100 400 200  5  5
# 4   C   A   2   2   2  2  2
# 5   B   B   3   3   3  3  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
d1 <- structure(list(id1 = c("A", "E", "D", "C", "B"), id2 = c("B", 
"B", "B", "A", "B"), X1 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), X2 = c(4L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 3L), X3 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), X4 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
3L), X5 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

d2 <- structure(list(id1 = c("A", "D", "E"), id2 = c("B", "B", "B"), 
    X1 = c(200, 100, 400), X2 = c(300, 400, 200), X3 = c(100, 
    200, 300), X4 = c(400, 300, 100)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 
2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. That creates a lot of duplicated rows: `df1` after the merge has 28 rows, whereas it should have 7, as before the merge. Any help?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Just change `all=TRUE` to `all.x=TRUE`. `all.x=` refers to df1 and `all.y=` to df2, and `all=` to both.

Comment: Sorry, `merge(df1[setdiff(names(df1), c("Sequ", "Utterance", "Aaoi", "Baoi", "Caoi",
                                        "Adur", "Bdur", "Cdur"))], 
              df2, all.x=TRUE)` still produces 28 rows

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Works fine for me with your sample data, getting 7 rows.

Comment: Okay, true, I now get only seven rows but the data in "Aaoi", "Baoi", "Caoi", "Adur", "Bdur", "Cdur" in the other rows of `df1` (for `Sequ == 30`) are all `NA`. How can they be kept?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann You would simply do the `merge` on a subset of rows, i.e. `merge(df1[1:7, c(...)], df2[1:7, ], ...)`.

Comment: Could you maybe put the complete solution into the answer post?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I was interrupted while answering your question, apologies. Please see my updated answer.